# Writing a set with a limit in its definition as a union and intersection of another set

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

I have the following problem from a past qualifying exam:

Let $\{f_k(x)\}_{k=1}^\infty$ be a sequence of non-negative measurable functions defined on $[0,1]$. For all integers $k,n\ge1$, define
$$E_k^n=\left\{x\in[0,1]:f_k(x)\ge\frac{1}{n}\right\}$$

Let $B=\{x\in[0,1]:\lim_{k\to\infty}f_k(x)\ne0 \text{ or does not exist}\}.$ Express $B$ in terms of $E_k^n$.

I can see that $$\cup_{n=1}^\infty E_k^n=\left\{x\in[0,1]:f_k(x)>0\right\}$$ and I can see that $$B=\{x\in[0,1]:\lim_{k\to\infty}f_k(x)>0 \text{ or does not exist}\}.$$

I'm not sure how to take care of the limit inside the set or the "does not exist" piece for that matter. I have a feeling I will need something of the form $\cap\cup E_k^n$ or $\cup\cap E_k^n$. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you able to express "$\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} f_k(x) \neq 0 \text{ or does not exist}$" as "not(some simpler condition)"?  There really is a trichotomy here.

Comment: @EricTowers Were you thinking something along the lines of $B=\{x\in[0,1]:\lim_{k\to\infty}f_k(x)=0\}^c$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this might do:

$$B=\{x\in[0,1]:\lim_{k\to\infty}f_k(x)>0 \text{ or does not exist}\}$$
$$=\{x\in[0,1]:\lim_{k\to\infty}f_k(x)=0\}^c$$
$$=\{x\in[0,1]:\forall n\in\mathbb{N}\;\exists N\in\mathbb{N} \text{ such that }k>N\implies f_k(x)<\frac{1}{n}\}^c$$
$$=\left(\cap_{n=1}^\infty\{x\in[0,1]:\exists N\in\mathbb{N}\text{ such that }k>N\implies f_k(x)<\frac{1}{n}\}\right)^c$$
$$=\left(\cap_{n=1}^\infty\cup_{N=1}^\infty\cap_{k>N}\{x\in[0,1]: f_k(x)<\frac{1}{n}\}\right)^c$$
$$=\cup_{n=1}^\infty\cap_{N=1}^\infty\cup_{k>N}E_k^n$$